# "One in 5 people is" OR "one in 5 people are"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which of the following is correct:

> 1. One in 5 people in that area **are** Chinese
> 2. One in 5 people in that area **is** a Chinese

I am confused as different resources provide a different answer.

One of the resources says that *people* is not the subject of the sentence. *One* is the subject and *in 5 people* is a prepositional phrase. Since “one” is singular, therefore the correct usage is
“One in 5 people in that area **is** a Chinese.”

However, I am not convinced with this argument. I have found the other usage almost everywhere else.

Comment: Please, please cite the resources and the explanations (or rules) they supply. It will show the community you have researched, and it might be interesting to see if how different resources approach the problem.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have updated my question to add some more details.

Comment: Both are possible. The subject has the plural "people" as head, so a plural verb would follow the simple agreement rule. But in this case, the verb can be singular as well as plural, where the optional singular override is clearly motivated by the presence of _one_.

Comment: @BillJ I would like to argue that we are not talking about `one` person. We are talking about a group of people. But I am not sure about it.

Comment: You didn't cite the resources. You haven't told us the titles of the books. Are they written in a foreign language? Interestingly, you wrote `One of the resources says`. You didn't use the plural form of the verb *say*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In `One of the resources says` we are talking about a single resource. But in `One in 5 people `, we are talking about a group of people. WDYT?

Comment: I only post answers in comments when a question is off-topic, very easy and doomed to be closed, or when I am not 100% convinced.

Comment: On the other hand, our friend @BillJ has a habit of writing answers in comments when the question is also on topic. Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: The subject is _One in 5 people in that area_. Agreement is normally with the head of the subject, which in this case is the plural noun _people_, but as I said, singular override is possible here.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence can be split up as so:

[One in 5] [people] [in that area] [are] [Chinese]

- [One in five] - describes/mopdified  the subject "people"
- [in that area] -just gives us a location that modifies the subject and tell us "what kind of people"
- [are] - verb, must agree with main subject "people"
- [Chinese] - is the object and irrelevant for your specific question.

"People" is the plural of person, therefore the correct answer is "are" and thus

(1) One in 5 people in that area are Chinese

Comment: If we expanded your answer, the logical inference would be that "One person in that area ARE Chinese" Hmm... `One person in five IS Chinese` or `For every five people, one IS Chinese`

Comment: No. "Person" is singular. So "one person is Chinese"

Comment: Yes, _one in 5_ functions as a determiner to the head word _people_. And I agree that plural _are_ follows the simple agreement rule. But singular agreement is also possible here partly because of the presence of _one_ and partly because of the synonymy with _One person in 5 in that area is Chinese_, where singular _person_ is head.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was still thinking of the original phrase with "people" not a new phrase "one person in 5"